# Does the image of a moving square under the map $(r,\theta) \mapsto (r,\theta +\log r)$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, symmetry, hausdorff-distance

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{0\}$ be defined in polar coordinates by $$ \phi:(r,\theta) \mapsto (r,\theta +\log r).$$

Let $S_n=[n-1,n+1]^2$ be a square of edge length $2$ centered around $(n,n)$.

Does $\phi(S_n)$ converges to a parallelogram when $n \to \infty$ w.r.t the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Properties) (up to a translation and rotation which depend on $n$)? If so, what are the edge-lengths/angles of that parallelogram? If not, does it converge to something else? Can we characterize the limit somehow?

Note that $\phi$ is area-preserving. It is the one-time flow of the divergence-free vector field $\log(r)\, \partial_{\theta}$.

Heuristically, when $n$ is very large, $r$ and $\theta$ are approximately constant along the square $S_n$. I am not sure how to use this formally though.

Note that the corner $C=(x_n,y_n)=(n+1,n+1)"="(r_n,\theta_n)=(\sqrt 2(n+1),\pi/4)$ of $S_n$ is mapped into
$$
\tilde C=(\tilde r_n,\tilde  \theta_n)=\big(\sqrt 2(n+1),\pi/4+\log (\sqrt 2(n+1))\big).
$$
and the corner $B=(x_n,y_n)=(n+1,n-1)"="(r_n,\theta_n)=(\sqrt 2\sqrt{n^2+1},\arctan{\frac{n-1}{n+1}})$ is mapped into
$$
\tilde B=(\tilde r_n,\tilde  \theta_n)=\big(\sqrt 2\sqrt{n^2+1},\arctan{\frac{n-1}{n+1}}+\log (\sqrt 2\sqrt{n^2+1})\big).
$$
Thus, I guess we first need to decide whether the images of the four corners converge (up to translations) to the vertices of a parallelogram.

The  difference of angles of $\tilde B,\tilde C$ diverges, since
$$
\log\big( \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\big)\to -\infty
$$
when $n \to \infty$. I am not sure  if this has any relevance though.

Below are pictures of $\operatorname{Image}(\phi)=\phi(S_n)$ for different values of $n$:

$n=2$:

[image]

$n=80$:

[image]

$n=800$:

[image]

Comment: up to a rotation maybe? do the four corners converge?

Comment: Yes you are right they do not converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question. The easiest is perhaps to linearize the problem in local coordinates around the center of $S_n$. So let $r_n=\sqrt{2}n$ be the radius to the center of $S_n$ and let us consider the image after making a backward rotation by an angle $-\log r_n$, thus fixing the center of $S_n$. Introducing local coordinates  $(x,y)=(n,n)+(x',y')$ with $x',y'$ of order 1 and writing $r=r_n+\delta r_n$ for the corresponding radii we have to first order: $\delta r_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x'+ y') + O(\frac1n)$ and then
up to error terms of $O(\frac1n)$:

$$ V_n = \log \frac{r}{r_n} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} =\frac{\delta r_n}{r_n} \times \left( -r\sin\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + r \cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)  = \frac{x'+y'}{2} \left( - \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} +\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\right) +O(\frac1n)$$
The limiting vector field $V_\infty$ gives rise to the linear shear flow, $V_\infty^t :(x',y')\mapsto (x',y')+\frac{t}{2} (x'+y')(-1,1)$ which at time one maps the square $S_n$ with corners $(-1,-1), (1,-1), (1,1),(-1,1)$ to a parallelogram with corners $(0,-2), (1,-1), (0,2), (-1,1)$.

Regarding rigorous bounds we use Gronwall's inequality: Consider a bounded convex neighborhood $B$ of the origin, say a ball of radius 3. For $n$ large we have that $V_n$ and $V_\infty$ are both uniformly $L$-Lipshitz in $B$ (the value depends on the chosen norm). We also have
$\|V_n - V_\infty\| \leq \frac{C}{n}$ as $n\to +\infty$. As long as the time $t$ flows of $p=(x',y')$ stays in such a neighborhood it follows that
$$ \| \frac{d}{dt} (V^t_n(p)-V^t_\infty(p)\| \leq \frac{C}{n} + L \|V^t_n(p)-V^t_\infty(p)\|. $$
By Gronwall's Lemma $\|V^t_n(p)-V^t_\infty(p)\|\leq \frac{C}{n} \frac{e^{Lt}-1}{L}$.
This implies that after rotation, $R_{-\log r_n} \circ\phi(S_n)=V_n^1(S_n)$ is at Hausdorff distance less than $\frac{C}{n} \frac{e^L-1}{L}$ from the parallelogram (for $n$ large enough).

Comment: Yes, a factor 1/2 was missing. For rigorous bounds you need something like Gronwall's Lemma so see that trajectories of the two flows stay close enough. I have added a sketch of a proof for such an estimate.

Comment: You were right about the sign. I think it is ok now. $c$ corresponds in fact to the time. So you may put $t=c$ in the time $t$ map.

Comment: Yes, I agree that $c=t$ is the time we flow; So just to be sure, the limit shape (of the time $t$-flow) would be $V^t_{\infty}([-1,1]^2)$?

Comment: yes, indeed that is the answer

Comment: Thank you. I have one last question: Suppose that we rotate the square $(n,n)+[-1,1]^2$ around its center $(n,n)$, i.e.  we start with $S_n=(n,n)+R_{\theta}([-1,1]^2)$, where $R_{\theta}$ is the standard rotation operator (matrix) corresponding to rotation of angle $\theta$ around the origin. Then the same result would hold, right? i.e. we would still get convergence of the images to a rectangle. (Formally, I guess all we need to do is change coordinates from $(x',y')$ into $R_{\theta}(x',y')$, right?)

Comment: In other words, all your analysis assumed was that $x',y'$ are of order $1$, the exact shape of the domain object doesn't matter. Even further than that, *any* moving shape whose diameter is of order $1$, would be "mapped in the limit" to an affine image of it. In other words, it is not the original shape that is crucial here, but the map itself that "converges" in this sense to a limiting affine map. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the map converges (uniformly on compacts) to the affine map $V^1_\infty$. The shape of the bounded object is irrelevant for this. Parallel lines are mapped to parallel lines, so a rotated square will also map to a parallelogram. But the angles in the corners of the resulting parallelogram will depend on your rotation angle.